# Scrollbar changes sides when a Bootstrap Modal opens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using [bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) to render modal windows.

When the site is RTL, the vertical scrollbar is on the right side. When a modal opens, the scrollbar on the right side disappears and another scrollbar appears on the left side.

This can be reproduced on the [demo site](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/).
Just `$("body").css("direction","rtl")` on the console to get the scrollbar to the right side and than open any modal.

Why is second scrollbar on the left side? How can I make it stay on the right side?

Comment: I don't see the scrollbar on the left. Also, what do you mean by "RTL"?

Comment: Also no scrollbar on the left. This is just Browser behaviour not related to twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: @KevinJantzer RTL probably means Right to left (arabic, hebrew websites...)

Comment: You don't get a change of sides of the vertical scrollbar once you open a modal (and set the direction of body to rtl before)?

Answer (score 1):

I see just the opposite.  When the site (body) is RTL, I *never* see the vert scrollbar on the right side.  Always on the left.  That's how it's "supposed" to be.

You can't change it -- at least not with a browser scrollbar.  It's on the left because that's where the scrollbar "belongs" when the direction of the site is RTL (at least according to the browser...some RTL readers think it is weird).

You can use a javascript plugin or roll your own custom scrollbars, but if you put it on the left when the site is RTL, you're changing the default browser behavior, and you're going to give yourself a lot of difficulties to integrate with bootstrap.

**EDIT**

Per my first comment below, I was viewing the demo page incorrectly.  Sorry.  The scrollbar that appears when the modal opens is on a div that represents the modal backdrop.  The browser applies this correctly according to the direction of the page being RTL.  But it's not the window's scrollbar that is flipping when the page is RTL; it's a div.

You can potentially use CSS to remove the scrollbar of the modal backdrop (around line 16 of http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css).

This has other consequences, however, and probably similar to the ones you're trying to avoid with the swap in direction of the window's main scrollbar.

Comment: The issue is not whether the vertical scrollbar is on the left or on the right, but that it changes sides when I open and closes a modal. You don't get this behavior?

Comment: I do, now that I checked again. Sorry.  On the demo page, I was confused because those <pre> tags DO have the proper placement of the scroll.  Edited answer.

Comment: Removing the scrollbar of `.modal-scrollable` is impossible since some modals are bigger higher than the screen. I noticed that when I change the direction of the `.modal-scrollable` to `ltr`, it's scrollbar goes to the right. I can than change the direction of the modal div itself so it will remain RTL. Could this be a solution? (if `body.direction` is `rtl`, set `.modal-scrollable.direction` to `ltr`)

Comment: If it works for you, I'd say it's a solution. These are tricky ones because they deal with user experience and expectations.  The browser behaves a certain way according to what it deems best.  If the user is expecting that, changing it can be negative.  But if it's 100% consistent across your entire app/site, it's less problematic.